# how to open pdf in webview android 6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I managed to open a pdf link inside a webview in android 4 and 5 but in android 6 the same code do not open , here my code

```
    webPDF = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webPDF);

    String auxPDF = "http://example link to pdf.pdf";
    webPDF.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webPDF.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webPDF.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webPDF.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ auxPDF);
```

i try this other codes too

```
webPDF.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webPDF.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

here the permissions to open in main activity:

```
     if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 123);
    }
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 123);
    }
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
    }
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
    }
```

the only thing that show is a blank screen on android 6.0.1!
any one can help me? thanks

Comment: Facing same issue with android 6.0.1.
Have you tried chrometab view ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
urlWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
urlWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
urlWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 private class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: i try it but i got blank screen again  ;/